# How do I debug java servlet Netbean tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, servlets

I know how to debug a Java application, this is my first time doing Java servlet project and using tomcat 8.0 in Netbean. When I click the debug , it show

```
"Stopping Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat..."
```

and the loading bar keep going on and nothing happen. I also want to know where is the project running as I did Sytem.out.printline, nothing is printed on the screen. Now as if I am coding blindly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug Java Web Application in Netbeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168301/how-to-debug-java-web-application-in-netbeans)

Comment: that didnt answer my question, I followed the step and it show "Stopping Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat..."

Comment: Did you read the second answer, about the project detaching itself from the debugger process?

Comment: Servlet is working on the serwer side so you have to look in the serwer log for your Sytem.out.printline

Comment: I did the second answer as well attached a JDPA debugger and the process just stopped "Stopping Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 2 minutes 5 seconds)"

Comment: @Kaa thank I manage to find in the stdout log